# Why replaceAll("*.<td>","<tr><td>Myval"); got error?

Tags: java

I got this `String s="<tr><td>Myval";`

I want to replace all Strings that is before `"<td>"` & include `"<td>"` to `""`;

```
 s=replaceAll("*.<td>",s);
```

So the result should be `s="Myval"`
But it got Runtime error.

```
   12:39:31.035 [ERROR]  Uncaught exception escaped
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0 
*.<td>
```

How to fix?

Comment: And your runtime error was...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: your question is not quite clear.

Comment: Dom parser is over complicated unnecessary

Comment: Yes, I showed its error in my question (updated question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular expressions, `*` quantifies the expression coming before it. Here, you've put a `*` at the beginning of the pattern, which is meaningless.

Maybe you wanted `".*<td>"`.